# Dart Web App with Access Control Measures

Tags: dart, access-control

So I am currently evaluating Dart's use as a potential language to re-write a campus organization's website. One critical aspect of this website is it's access control policies. It seems that anything written within the Dart web apps could potentially be compromised, and thus led me to asking the following question.

Is it possible to securely implement access-control to pages in Dart, using either just a web app or a combination of a web app and a dart-implemented server? Could it also be possible to implement that same concept using Apache with a proxy-passthrough to dart?

Comment: You can use Casbin-Dart: https://github.com/casbin/casbin-dart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you actually want to achieve with a proxy-passthrough.

When you create a single page app in Dart all client code is loaded to the client. This is normally no security concern. When a view is shown it usually loads data from a server. Here you enforce security.

You can require the user to authenticate and decide in the server code if or which data you serve for this user or what update command you allow the user to execute. You can just return an error when the user invokes a function that he is not allowed to use.

Comment: Ok  clearly i have not understood how dart is deployed then. Lets say i have two pages, and and b. Page a is open to the public and page b requires you to log in. How can i go about forcing that login requirement using dart?

Comment: You can show a minimal view at first and after the user logged in you can change the view to show all options but in the end the security needs to be enforced on the server. Anybody could write another client app that acts as if the user has already been logged in and accesses your server. On the client side you its all about user experience, on the server side its all about security. Usually security is not about what forms you show to the user but which data one can fetch from the server or write back to the server.